# AngularJS Directive Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been trying to affect an variable in the parent scope to toggle ng-show from inside a directive. The directive is custom directive containing an ng-repeat directive. The idea, is that once the ng-repeat finishes, I want to hide the containing div as well as the elements inside of it.

Here's a Plunkr demonstrating my situation: http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/C42Z25?p=preview
Also here's a comparison in JSFiddle, which uses the same problem, but it's not an ng-repeat and so it works: http://jsfiddle.net/dyzPC/

So there's several problems. Inside my directive, I have to use `scope.$parent.showMe = true` to change the parent scope's `showMe`, I can't seem to just use `scope.showMe = true` to set it. I tried with isolate scopes, no scopes, true scopes, nothing seems to work.

Furthermore, in a jquery callback function I cannot seem to reset the parent scope showMe as `scope.$parent.showMe = false`. This prevents me from showing the containing div when there's content, and hiding it when there's no content.

On a side note, one final problem is the usage of `$last`. In the plunkr example, using $last is possible, but in my real code, the ng-repeat collection is being filled up from an HTTP response interceptor. This seems to prevent $last from be used, as all the elements end up as `$last = true`. Is there a another way to detect when an ng-repeat has finished?

Comment: i can help with setting the parent value. i had the same problem setting values in a directive.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494457/how-to-set-an-interpolated-value-in-angluar-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your directive, you need to wrap `scope.$parent.showMe = false;` in `scope.$apply()`:

```
scope.$parent.showMe = true; //this one works
element.hide().fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
   scope.$apply(function(){
      scope.$parent.showMe = false;
   });
});
```

This is because you are changing the value of an Angular property outside of Angular (your jQuery function) so Angular doesn't know `scope.showMe` has changed.

You directive is in the same tag as your `ngRepeat`, you can't use an isolate scope as it would remove the bind for your `ng-repeat="httpMessage in messages"`. In other words, `httpMessages` wouldn't exist if you isolated the scope here.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the hide/show logic and the ng-repeat down into the directive, and then let the controller feed the directive the list of messages through the directive's attributes.

```
app.directive("hideShow", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 
    "<div ng:repeat='message in messages'>" +
    "  <em>{{message.message}}</em> " +
    "</div>",
    scope: {
        messages: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.hide();
        scope.$watch("messages", function() {
            element.fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');               
        });
    }
};
});
```

Here's a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yStR/1/).