# how to set an interpolated value in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How do I set the interpolated value in a directive?  I can read the correct value from the following code, but I have not been able to set it.

**js:**

```js
app.directive('ngMyDirective', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.ngMyDirective));

        //set the interpolated attrs.ngMyDirective value somehow!!!
    }
});
```

**html:**

```js
<div ng-my-directive="myscopevalue"></div>
```

where `myscopevalue` is a value on my controller's scope.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to set a value on the scope but don't know the name of the property (ahead of time), you can use `object[property]` syntax:

```javascript
scope[attrs.myNgDirective] = 'newValue';
```

If the string in the attribute contains a dot (e.g. `myObject.myProperty`), this won't work; you can use `$eval` to do an assignment:

```javascript
// like calling  "myscopevalue = 'newValue'"
scope.$eval(attrs.myNgDirective + " = 'newValue'");
```

[Update: You should really use `$parse` instead of `$eval`. See [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16499325/62082).]

If you're using an isolate scope, you can use the `=` annotation:

```javascript
app.directive('ngMyDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            theValue: '=ngMyDirective'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // will automatically change parent scope value
            // associated by the variable name given to `attrs.ngMyDirective`
            scope.theValue = 'newValue';
        }
    }
});
```

You can see an example of this in [this Angular/jQuery color picker JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/x2uwQ/), where assigning to `scope.color` inside the directive automatically updates the variable passed *into* the directive on the controller's scope.

Comment: scope[attrs.myNgDirective] = 'newValue'; worked!  although the value of myNgDirective has to be directly on the scope, not a sub object of the scope.   which makes sense

Comment: I believe you should be able to `$eval` with an assignment expression for object notation; I'll update my answer.

Comment: that would be cool. something like  scope.$eval(attrs.ngMyDirective = 'new value') ?

Comment: Almost; you'd want to `$eval` the string exactly as you'd pass it into something like `ng-init`. I've updated the answer with an example, and also an example of the isolate scope version.

Comment: excellent that is exactly what i need.  i am upvoting in spirit now because the stack wont let me do it more than once

Comment: Haha, it's appreciated. ;)

Comment: I prefer `$parse` over `$eval`.  See my answer for more info.

Comment: Of course! Totally forgot about $parse. That is the correct answer.

Answer (score 45):

Whenever a directive does not use an isolate scope and you specify a scope property using an attribute, and you want to change that property's value, I suggest using [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse). (I think the syntax is nicer than $eval's.)

```
app.directive('ngMyDirective', function ($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.ngMyDirective);
        console.log(model(scope));
        model.assign(scope,'Anton');
        console.log(model(scope));
    }
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/xDDxH/)</kbd>

`$parse` works whether or not the attribute contains a dot.

Comment: interesting stuff.  thanks for the answer. You may have a point that parse may be a better term/syntax to use than eval. cheers

Comment: That's definitely the right way to implement '=' without scope isolation.

Comment: I had to add a `scope.$apply()` after the `model.assign(...)` in order to make the change of my directive reflected in the view. Is there any cleaner solution ?

Comment: Do you have a solution if the directive is inside a loop ? In such situation, this is always the first item which get updated.

Comment: This is a powerful technique and just what I was looking for.  For instance, I wasn't able to find JSON assignment in the $eval space, but this solution works for that.

Comment: Note that Object.assign() not supported in Internet Explorer, [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibilit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Dhaval, that's not Object.assign().  It is a different function -- it is the assign() "function property" of the function returned by $parse.  See the [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) doc.