# How i can access the scope vars mentioned in attributes

Tags: angularjs

For a datepicker control i added some custom attributes to the input element:

```
<input id="inputDatepicker" ng-model="currentAppointment.date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" datepicker changedates="currentAppointment.start">
```

For that i created a directive to build the datepicker:

```
.directive('datepicker', function ($filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes, $ctrl) {       

        $scope[$attributes.changedates] ... do not work

        $element.datepicker();    
      }
    }
});
```

How i can access the scope vars mentioned in the changedates-attribute? In my example above i want to access `$scope.currentAppointment.start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) service:

```
var model = $parse($attributes.changedates)
```

to get value

```
model($scope)
```

to set value

```
model.assign($scope, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to set/change the value of `currentAppointment.start` in your directive, and you need to detect when the value changes, use `$watch` (instead of `$parse`):

```js
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.changedates, function(value) {
        console.log('value=', value);
    });
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/KzkQG/)</kbd> - in the fiddle, I included a button that changes the value of `currentAppointment.start`, so you can observe the watch noticing the change (via the console).

Comment: if I understand correctly, one should use $parse when there is an isolated scope and the value need to change. Otherwise use $watch ?
What about $eval ?

Comment: @FlorianF, use $parse or $watch or $eval to get the value.  Use $watch if the value may change -- i.e., your directive needs to react to changes to the value.  Use $parse when there is NOT an isolated scope and the directive needs to be able to change the value ($eval can also be used, but it is not as clean: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16494482/215945)).

Comment: Ok I see, thanks! If I understand correctly, a good use of $eval is when the value won't change and if the directive doesn't need to change the value.